# How to broadcast to sender only?

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe, broadcast

I know broadcast is for others to get the message in real-time. But for some reason I need it to be received only by sender. How to achieve this? Right now, the broadcast is received by all excerpt for the sender.
I'm using `redis+ socket.io + laravel event + laravel queue`

I did try something like passing the logged in user id in the broadcast message from server side and then from client side check if the login id match with the one coming from server. Then only reveal the message. But it seems like, somewhere is configured that sender wont get the message. It's only subscribed by other users connected to the socket.

So how can I control it from server side? How can I make the sender subscribe to this particular channel?

> DashboardEvent file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class DashboardEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $actionId;
    public $actionData;
    public $user;


    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @author Author
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($actionId, $actionData, $user)
    {
        $this->actionId = $actionId;
        $this->actionData = $actionData;
        $this->user = $user;

    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @author Author
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        // return new Channel('action-channel-one');
         return [new Channel('action-channel-one')];
    }

    /**
     * Get the data to broadcast.
     *
     * @author Author
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        
        return [
            'actionId' => $this->actionId,
            'actionData' => $this->actionData,
            'sender'=>$this->user
        ];
    }

}
```

> socket.js file

```
'use strict';
 var cors = require('cors');
var app = require('express')();
 app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
require('dotenv').config();

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('connected'+socket.id);

});

var redisPort = process.env.REDIS_PORT;
var redisHost = process.env.REDIS_HOST;
var ioRedis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new ioRedis(redisPort, redisHost);

redis.subscribe('test_database_action-channel-one');

redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {
  message  = JSON.parse(message);
  console.log(message);
  io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
  
});

var broadcastPort = process.env.BROADCAST_PORT;
server.listen(broadcastPort, function () {
  console.log('Socket server is running.');
});
```

> client side

```
var sock = io("http://127.0.0.1:3444", {
      transports: ['websocket']
   });
   var sender = "{{ auth()->check() ? Auth::id() : 'false' }}";
  

   sock.on('test_database_action-channel-one:App\\Events\\DashboardEvent', function (data) {
   console.log(data);

   var action = data.actionId;
   var actionData = data.actionData;
   var user = data.sender;

   //if sender
   if (user == sender) {
    console.log('this is the sender');
   }

   });
```

Comment: If you need to broadcast back to the sender, consider using the [ACK functionality in socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/#Acknowledgements)

Comment: but it should happen on event trigger

Comment: I found that the sender is not listening to the channel